# 500 Internal Server Error on uploading file more than 100 KB

Tags: javascript, java, html

index.html

```
id="myFile" enclosed in div tag

<div id = "myFile">

</div>
```

controller.js

```
    $("#myFile").uploadFile({
        url:/Spot_audit/upload/"+id+"/"+year",
        fileName:$scope.myFile,
        allowedTypes: "zip,docx,xlsx,7z",
            maxFileSize:5*1024*1024
    });
```

controller.java

```
/*   file upload    */    

@RequestMapping(value="/upload/{Id}/{fy}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void handleFileUpload (@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @PathVariable("fy") String year, @PathVariable("Id") String aid){                   
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        String path1="C:/Users/Downloads/"+month+"/"+aid+"/"+file.getOriginalFilename();

        Path path= Paths.get(path1);

        try{
                File newFile1 = new File(path);
            newFile1.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            newFile1.createNewFile();
            BufferedOutputStream os1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newFile1));

            os1.write(file.getBytes(), 0, (int) file.getSize());
            os1.flush();
            os1.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            CompPath="";            
        }           
    }

    //return new ResponseEntity<String>(fullpath, HttpStatus.CREATED); 
}
```

}

Comment: Would you mind formatting your code nicely and removing empty lines ? Where does your code run ? Tomcat ? I assume you are hitting a limit of your application server which needs to be increased in order to retrieve bigger files. For Tomcat you can find the relevant docs here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html. Besides that it would be a good idea to have a look at the server logs, there you might see the details of the 500 error.

Comment: You've got a bad code formatting. Please, add more text comments and format your code in order to make other people understand and solve your problem.

Comment: What webserver are you using? What's the request timeout? What's the maximum allowed filesize of the webserver?

Comment: Besides that: I am not sure if this will work, but you should test what happens if someone is able to smuggle in some `../../../` into your filename

Answer (score 1):

As the problem only occurs with files bigger than 100 KB you are running into a limit imposed by your application server.

Normally a rather low limit is set in order to keep "malicious" users from uploading files too big in size. You have to raise this maximum POST limit in order to get bigger files through.

The setting depends on the application server / servlet container you use.

If you want to change the value directly in the server settings and your server is Tomcat, have a look here: 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

You can define the same value in your web.xml:

```
<multipart-config>
    <location>/tmp</location>
    <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
    <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
    <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

It is even possible to raise the value from code:

```
@MultipartConfig(location="/tmp", fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024, 
    maxFileSize=1024*1024*5, maxRequestSize=1024*1024*5*5)
```

(both taken from https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html)

If your code is based on Spring Boot there is an alternative to this which only needs you to set a configuration value in application.properties. This setting should work for all [containers supported](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html) by Spring Boot (Tomcat 7-8, Jetty 8-9, Undertow)

```
multipart.maxFileSize: 128KB
multipart.maxRequestSize: 128KB
```

(this time taken from https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)

Comment: Thanks Marged will try this